# How we can check there are no more events or messages is left on the topic to consume?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-data-jpa, spring-kafka

Is there a way we can check there are no more events or messages is left on the topic to consume in Spring Boot Kafka. In my scenario, I have a requirement like I receive data from the two-channel source one from Kafka topic, and another I can get a complete dump of data by connecting to some other DB. So there is a case after consuming all the messages from Kafka Topic I need to compare the count of data that I have received from Topic with the other data count which I get from DB connectivity.

Is it possible to do so? I know how to write the code in spring boot to start consuming events from Kafka topic and how to make a DB connectivity get data from one DB table and insert it another db table

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#idle-containers) about detecting idle listener containers.

> While efficient, one problem with asynchronous consumers is detecting when they are idle. You might want to take some action if no messages arrive for some period of time.

> You can configure the listener container to publish a ListenerContainerIdleEvent when some time passes with no message delivery. While the container is idle, an event is published every idleEventInterval milliseconds.

> ...